# Pantheon show thumbnails samba server

Tags: pantheon-files, samba

I just installed a samba server and my files are now accessable via samba. For any reason I can't see any thumbnails in the samba files. Is there an option to change the settings for Pantheon to display no local files with thumbnails?

Answer (score 1):

Files is intentionally set to not thumbnail remote files by default in order to reduce network traffic.

There is a branch to provide an option to turn thumbnailing on - see:

lp:~jeremywootten/pantheon-files/fix-1458398-option-thumbnail-remote

but it needs some more work and other branches have a higher priority.